# Дата поста Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В шаблоне single.php использую 2 цикла

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="blogItemText">
                            <p class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
                            <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                            <?php the_content('', FALSE, ''); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

и

```
<?php
                        global $post;
                        $args = array("category" => $blogId, "posts_per_page" => 3, "orderby" => "date");
                        $posts = get_posts( $args );
                        foreach( $posts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post); ?>
                            <div class="blogItem">
                                <div class="dateBox">
                                    <?php the_date("d M"); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="textBox">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Первый выводит текущий пост, второй выводит 3 поста. Проблема заключается в том, что во втором цикле у первого поста не отображается дата.[image: страница поста]
При удалении `<?php the_date(); ?>` из первого цикла дата у первого поста второго цикла появляется. Дата исчезает только у первого поста и если он выводится через первый цикл, т.е. при открытии любого другого поста проблемы нет.
Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что если в выборке есть несколько постов с одинаковой датой, то the_date выведет дату только для первого из них.
Вместо функции the_date() используйте функцию the_time():

```
<?php
                    global $post;
                    $args = array("category" => $blogId, "posts_per_page" => 3, "orderby" => "date");
                    $posts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $posts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post); ?>
                        <div class="blogItem">
                            <div class="dateBox">
                                <?php the_time("d M"); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="textBox">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```